# what is the easy way to search a pattern from an array into another array?

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, scripting

```
arrayA=( ab xy )
arrayB=( abkpi xyert )
```

I need to search the pattern of `arrayA` into `arrayB`. If any pattern doesn't match into `arrayB`, the script should return the flag `false` in bash shell.

Comment: Which shell are you using?

Comment: This looks more like a general programming question to me than a bash question. How about a nested loop - outer loop runs over arrayA, inner loop over arrayB?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to provide more info about what you want to do.
If we take literally your words " If any pattern doesn't match into arrayB, the script should return the flag false in bash shell." then this can be done like this:

```
root@debi64: A=( ab xy );B=( abkpi xyert );for Ad in "${A[@]}";do if [[ "${B[@]}" =~ "$Ad" ]];then echo "$Ad found in array B";else echo "$Ad not found in Array B";fi;done
ab found in array B
xy found in array B

root@debi64: A=( aa xy );B=( abkpi xyert );for Ad in "${A[@]}";do if [[ "${B[@]}" =~ "$Ad" ]];then echo "$Ad found in array B";else echo "$Ad not found in Array B";fi;done
aa not found in Array B
xy found in array B

root@debi64:A=( ab xx );B=( abkpi xyert );for Ad in "${A[@]}";do if [[ "${B[@]}" =~ "$Ad" ]];then echo "$Ad found in array B";else echo "$Ad not found in Array B";fi;done
ab found in array B
xx not found in Array B

root@debi64:A=( ak xt );B=( abkpi xyert );for Ad in "${A[@]}";do if [[ "${B[@]}" =~ "$Ad" ]];then echo "$Ad found in array B";else echo "$Ad not found in Array B";fi;done
ak not found in Array B
xt not found in Array B
```

But is this enough for your goal?
I suspect not.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk. Read the arrays into awk using process substitutions.
Example where all items are found in the other array:

```
$ awk -v RS=' ' 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} !($1 in a){exit 1}' <(echo ${arrayA[*]}) <(echo ${arrayA[*]})
$ echo $?
0
```

and another where none are found. Awk exits and returns `1` once it meets the first item in `arrayB` which is not in `arrayA`:

```
$ awk -v RS=' ' 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} !($1 in a){exit 1}' <(echo ${arrayA[*]}) <(echo ${arrayB[*]})
$ echo $?
1
```